# Do not repeat the last used background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make the next background color I use not repeat the last one used?
ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

```
<div class="sus"id="change">

</div>
<div class="sus"id="change" >

</div>
<div class="sus"id="change" >

</div>
<div class="sus"id="change" >

</div>
<div class="sus"id="change" >

</div>
<div class="sus"id="change" >

</div>
```

--

```
let colores = ["#7579CD", "#7593CD", "#75C8CD", "#75CDAD","#A175CD", "CD7575"]

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
start()});
function start() {
    item = document.querySelectorAll(".sus")

    document.querySelectorAll('.sus').forEach(item => {
        
            item.style.backgroundColor = colores[Math.floor(Math.random() * colores.length)]
            
    })}
```

Comment: keep the generated color in a variable and assign it to the div.  later before assigning another color to another div check the color variable if it was already generated or not...if generated re-run the random function and now set the new color in the variable...

Comment: what is the point of using identical IDs, then the principle of an ID is to be able to identify an element among the others and that it is precisely for this reason that it is called an identifier...?

Comment: The answers you are getting are tackling two different questions. Could you clarify what is required? Do you want to not use the last used color or do you want to not repeat a color at all?

Comment: @MisterJojo I know, I only made the first script for a single div with one id, but then I copied and pasted that div several times.

Comment: what do you expect from me? that I congratulate you for leaving wrong code even when it is pointed out to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method would be to maintain the last used color in a variable and check every time if the new color is not the same as last color.

```
function start() {
  item = document.querySelectorAll(".sus")

  let lastColor = null;

  document.querySelectorAll('.sus').forEach(item => {
    let newColor = null;
    do {
      newColor = colores[Math.floor(Math.random() * colores.length)]
    } while (newColor === lastColor);

    item.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
    lastColor = newColor;

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `let i = 0` before entering the loop, then use
`item.style.backgroundColor = colores[i]; i++;`
or
if you must do it randomly, I suggest you copy the array of colors and remove the color in every iteration of `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

You need the following logic. Use memoization technique to save the last value.

```
function start() { 
  
    item = document.querySelectorAll(".sus")
   let color='';
    document.querySelectorAll('.sus').forEach(item => {
      
      color= getNonRepeatableColor(color); 

      item.style.backgroundColor = color;
       
})}
       
function getNonRepeatableColor(lastColor){

      let nextColor=colores[Math.floor(Math.random() *       colores.length)];
  
  if(nextColor===lastColor){ 
   return getNonRepeatableColor(lastColor);
  }

  return nextColor;
}
```

Use recursion for every time you encounter a case where the last color equals the current value in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that no color is used more than once then, when you have picked a color, you can remove it from the array so it can't be used again.

This snippet uses the JavaScript function filter to remove all instances of the picked color from the array of colors.

```js
let colores = ["#7579CD", "#7593CD", "#75C8CD", "#75CDAD", "#A175CD", "#CD7575"]

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  start()
});

function start() {

  document.querySelectorAll('.sus').forEach(item => {
    const col = colores[Math.floor(Math.random() * colores.length)];
    item.style.backgroundColor = col;
    colores = colores.filter(color => color != col);
  })
}
```

```css
.sus {
  /* just for demo */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<style>

</style>
<div class="sus">

</div>
<div class="sus">

</div>
<div class="sus">

</div>
<div class="sus">

</div>
<div class="sus">

</div>
<div class="sus">

</div>
```

If however you want to just make sure that no two adjacent colors are the same (ie that the picked color isn't the same as the last color), you can use a temporary copy of the array which has the color removed so it can't be picked.

```js
let colores = ["#7579CD", "#7593CD", "#75C8CD", "#75CDAD", "#A175CD", "#CD7575"]

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  start()
});

function start() {
  let copy = colores.slice();

  document.querySelectorAll('.sus').forEach(item => {
    const col = copy[Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length)];
    item.style.backgroundColor = col;
    copy = colores.slice().filter(color => color != col);
  })
}
```

```css
.sus {
  /* just for the demo */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<style>

</style>
<div class="sus">

</div>
<div class="sus">

</div>
<div class="sus">

</div>
<div class="sus">

</div>
<div class="sus">

</div>
<div class="sus">

</div>
```

Note: your code had several errors which have been corrected in these snippets.

The repeated use of the same id is not legal HTML. ids must be unique.

The last color in the array was missing the # color, which led to some .sus divs not getting a color set.

And, not an error, but redundant, was the setting of item at the beginning of the start function.

Note also that the methods used here ensure that the same *color* is not picked twice - it does not work on the indexes within colores. So if you have two items in colores with the same color then it will not work for the first scenario unless there are equal or more different colors in colores than there are .sus elements.